# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you help me, please? When I run this, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined" in the 'bindTaskEvents' function where the function deals with the "completedTasksHolder" list. Trying this in the console:

```
console.log(completedTasksHolder.children[0])
```

returns the only li just fine.

```
var taskInput = document.getElementById("new-task"); // new-task
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]; // first button
var incompleteTasksHolder = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks"); // ul#incomplete-tasks
var completedTasksHolder = document.getElementById("completed-tasks"); // ul#completed-tasks

// Add a new task
var addTask = function(){
    console.log("Add task...");
}
// Edit an existing task
var editTask = function() {
    console.log("Edit task...");
}

var deleteTask = function() {
    console.log("Delete task...");
// Delete an existing task

    // When the Delete button is pressed
        // Remove the parent li from the ul
}

var taskCompleted = function() {
    console.log("Complete task...");
// Mark a task as complete
    // When the checkbox is checked
        // Append the task li to the #completed-tasks
}

// Mark a task as incomplete
var taskIncomplete = function() {
    console.log("Incomplete task...");
    // When the checkbox is unchecked
        // Append the task li to the #incomplete-tasks
}

var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
    console.log("Bind li events");
    // select li's children
    var checkbox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    // bind editTask to editButton
    editButton.onclick = editTask;

    //  bind deleteTask to deleteButton;
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

    // bind checkBoxEventHandler to checkbox
    checkbox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;
}

// Set the click handler to the addTask function
addButton.onclick = addTask;

// Cycle over incompleteTasksHiolder ul list items
for (var i = 0; incompleteTasksHolder.children.length; i++) {
        // bind events to li' children (taskCompleted)
    bindTaskEvents(incompleteTasksHolder.children[i], taskCompleted);
}     

// Cycle over completedTasksHiolder ul list items

for (var i = 0; completedTasksHolder.children.length; i++) {
        // bind events to li' children (taskCompleted)
    bindTaskEvents(completedTasksHolder.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}
```

What can be wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What is `incompleteTasksHolder.children[i]` ?

Comment: It is the ul (container) with list items as the children

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is with the for loop

Replace

```
for (var i = 0; incompleteTasksHolder.children.length; i++) {
```

with

```
for (var i = 0; i < incompleteTasksHolder.children.length; i++) {
```

and similarly for `completedTasksHolder`

Bascially you have created a loop with no end condition and at some point `incompleteTasksHolder.children[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @NikolayKomolov Welcome, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. ```js
   var db = null;
   var db2 = null;
   var db3 = null;
   var dbUser = null;
   var dbName = "estudos.db";

   var app = {
       // Application Constructor
       initialize: function() {
           document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
       },

       // deviceready Event Handler
       //
       // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
       // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
       onDeviceReady: function() {
           this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
       },

       // Update DOM on a Received Event
       receivedEvent: function(id) {
           var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
           var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
           var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

           listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
           receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');


           // OPERACOES BD - inicio

           //banco de dados local - aceite de termos e outras coisas
           dbUser = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'user.db', location: 'default'});
           dbUser.transaction(function(tx) {
               tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (flg_aceite, flg_valid_bd)');
           }, function(error) {
               alert('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
           }, function() {
               console.log('Database OK');
           });

           //copia do banco de dados de estudos
           window.plugins.sqlDB.copy(dbName, 0, copysuccess, copyerror);
           // OPERACOES BD - fim
       }
   };

   app.initialize();

   //---------------------------------------------------------------

   function copysuccess()
   {
       //primeira versão deste banco de dados. o comando anterior.
       //provavelmente realizou a cópia, abro o BD.
       db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: dbName});
       //preciso verificar se existem versões anteriores deste BD. Deleto por precaucao
       dropTable();
       fts_table();
   }

   function copyerror(e)
   {
       //esta versao do banco de dados ja existe.
       //abro o BD
       db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: dbName});
       //db3 = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "vtestudos"});
       //alert("copyerror" + JSON.stringify(e));
   }


   //---------------------------------------------------------------

   function fts_table(){
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
       tx.executeSql('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE vtestudos USING FTS3(titulo, texto, id_titulo)', [], function(tx,res){
             //alert("nao deu erro");
             //db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "vtestudos"});
             //alert("uai. deu pra abrir");

             db.transaction(function(tx) {
             tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO vtestudos(titulo, texto, id_titulo) SELECT titulo, texto, id_titulo FROM estudos', [], function(tx,res){
                 //db3 = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "vtestudos"});
                  console.log('insert ok');
             });
             }, function(err){
                 alert(err.message);
             });

       });
       }, function(err){
           alert(err.message);
       });
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------------

   function dropTable()
   {
       window.plugins.sqlDB.remove("estudosprev1", 0, rmsuccess,rmerror); 
       window.plugins.sqlDB.remove("estudosprev2", 0, rmsuccess,rmerror);  
   }

   function rmsuccess()
   {
       //existe versão anterior
       //alert("removesuccess");
       console.log('existe versão anterior');
   }

   function rmerror(e)
   {
       //não existe versão anterior. ignoro.
       //alert("removeerror" + JSON.stringify(e));
       console.log('n existe versão anterior. ignoro.');
   }
   ```

Comment: any details, what it does ?

Comment: It make the functions to execute the code in database.But when it´s executed  in Android Studio. Show the error code:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null".                                                      It´s my index.js file. I don´t no if you already had it issue when executed using phonegap/cordova in Android Studio.                                       Thanks